How to generate regex code for input field to include partial urls e.g /abouts-us
Im trying to generate a code that would allow an input field to accept full and partial urls, my regex for the full url is fine, however; im having issues with the partialUrlRegex . I would like it to follow the following format: slashes at the start and/or end, multiple path slashes like so below:

/about-us
about-us/team
/sheerwood.co.uk/connect/news
sheerwood.co.uk/connect/news/
/sheerwood.co.uk/connect/news/
must not allow numbers or digits on thier own
must not allow just plain string.

Code so far:
// Custom URL validator that allows both full URLs and partial paths

defineRule('custom_url', (value) => {

    const fullUrlRegex = /^(https?:\/\/[^\s$.?#].[^\s]*)$/;
    const partialUrlRegex = /^(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+(\/[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+)*\/?)$/;  

    if (fullUrlRegex.test(value) || partialUrlRegex.test(value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return 'Please enter a valid URL (e.g., https://example.com or /about-us)';
});


Can you please describe the issues with your current partial url regex?

why is about-us/team allowed? it does not have "slashes at the start and/or end"

apparently the second last rule is not covered by the final rule so what does "on their own" mean? how do numbers differ from digits? Is 1.23 a number? 4e7? one hundred billion?

Could you instead of describing "must not allow numbers or digits on their own" and
"must not allow just plain string" update the question with some more examples of what should and should not match? Like should /about-us/123 or 1/about-us or /sheerwood.co.uk/connect/12/news/ or /sheerwood.co.uk/connect/12.34/news/ match?
